# Call bash random function inside cat file lines

Tags: bash, cat

The goal is to use the bash function inside the cat lines that creates an html file.

Must be easy knowing the way, but this does not "compile" while writing at Sublime:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function create_file_with_random_numbers {

    file="/User/example/folder/random_numbers.html"

    bash -c cat <<EOF >${file}

    Your random numbers are: "[ { $(( RANDOM % 70 ))  } and { $(( RANDOM % 70 ))  } ]"

EOF

}
```

I tried to scape the cat file with ", [, {, etc., is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: The code, as presented, should work (although it's strange and not generate a valid html). Instead of `bash -c cat`, just `cat`. What exactly is your question? What exactly "is possible"? bash does not "compile" scripts, scripts are parsed and executed, there is no "compilation" involving.

Comment: Is it possible to call the random function inside the cat lines?

Comment: Did you try it? Did you try to answer the question on your own? There are no "cat lines", there is no such term. And yes, the arithmetic expansion is expanded inside a here document. Take a look at [bash manual here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents)  if "EOF" `is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion .....` The `$(( ))` is a arithmetic expansion.

Comment: You are right. The script works. My bad. Thanks.

Comment: Calm down. Someone comes here to learn. If I do not express my self properly, please have in count English is a second language to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf`:

```
printf 'Your random numbers are: "[ { %d } and { %d } ]"\n' "$(( RANDOM % 70 ))" "$(( RANDOM % 70 ))" > "$file"
```